# What rep is required to see upvotes/downvotes?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I was just wondering what rep is required to see the votes on a question? I.e. Total upvotes/total downvotes. I am of mixed rep over several SE sites so I can't specifically remember.

Answer (score 2):

1000 - see https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Comment: Simple question, simple answer :) cheers!